# Tengo un problema con la instalación en otras maquinas de mi sistema

Tags: c#

Cree un sistema en c# el cual cree el setup para instalarlo en las terminales y en algunas se cierra de la nada, alguien sabría que esta pasando?
No arroja ningún error ni mensajes solo se cierra

Comment: Tienes que añadirle funcionalidad al setup para que genere un log en cada ejecución. Lo otro es ver el visor de eventos de Windows. De resto, es imposible saberlo sin saber qué hace tu setup